# Binding images to the background

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, mef

In my WPF project I am using Prism + MEF + MVVM.

In Main Window (I mean Shell.xaml) there has to be a background (*image* or *.wmv file*). But this has to be able to change any time (Changes will occurred with view changes). **Some views has image, some has movie**. I could use images as the background of Views in Modules. But movie files are not proper. **While changing, they all start from beginning. I want it to continue if movie is same as the previous view background movie.**

In Internet I couldn't found any source/problem about this.

Is there any one who could help me?

Comment: "I want it to continue if movie is same as the previous view background movie." For this, you can track position of movie and apply when new starts.

Comment: @Neeraj Thanks for your help, but the description for this background situation isn't like that. It has to change with view changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the Background in the ParentViewModel, and be sure to only fire the PropertyChanged event if the value has changed.

```
public object WindowBackground
{
    get {return _windowBackground; }
    set
    {
        if (_windowBackground != value)
        {
            _windowBackground = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("WindowBackground");
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use something like Prism's `EventAggregator` to fire a `BackgroundChangeEvent` which the parent ViewModel can subscribe to, so all ViewModels can update the background.